# How to cast VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP?

Tags: timestamp, teradata, varchar

I need to convert `VARCHAR` to `TIMESTAMP`

This works only when the month has two digits

```
SEL CAST('12/25/1994 11:46:29 PM'  AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'mm-DD-YYYYBhh:mi:ssBt' )
```

However, when the month has one digit this fails

```
SEL CAST('1/2/1994 11:46:29 PM'  AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'mm-DD-YYYYBhh:mi:ssBt' )
```

How to account to month with one digit ?

Comment: Have you tried varying the format string? e.g.` 'm-DD-YYYYBhh:mi:ssBt'`

Answer (score 1):

First, your date has `/` as separator but you're using `-` in your `CAST` format. However that's not your main problem.

Apparently Teradata `CAST` formats only works with two digit months and days, if you are sure that your data is well formatted and this is the only problem that you have, you can try something like this.

```
SELECT
    '1/2/1994 11:46:29 PM' AS YourDate,
    CAST(CASE
        WHEN YourDate LIKE '_/_/%' THEN '0' || SUBSTRING(YourDate FROM 1 FOR 2) || '0' || SUBSTRING(YourDate FROM 3) 
        WHEN YourDate LIKE '_/__/%' THEN '0' || YourDate
        ELSE YourDate
     END AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'mm/dd/YYYYBhh:mi:ssBt')
```

Other alternative is the function `TO_TIMESTAMP`. It allows single digit days, but not single digit months.